# Conditional type in function argument resolves to 'undefined', but it is still required to be provided

Tags: typescript

In this code, `activateState()` has `state` and `params` arguments. `params` is a destructured object that can have `fooParams` and `barParams` properties with conditional types that can resolve to `undefined`, based on value of `state`, which is a generic.

Next, `activateState()` is called with `started` state, which has only `fooParams` defined in `params`. `params` object is provided with `fooParams`, but with no `barParams`, since it resolved to `undefined`.

```js
type StateName = 'started' | 'ended';

type StateNameWithParams = 'started';
    
type StateNameWithFooParams = 'started';
type StateNameWithBarParams = never;

type StateParams = {
    'started': {
        fooParams: {
            abc: string
        },
        barParams: {}
    }
}

function activateState<
    T extends StateName,
>(
    state: T, {
        fooParams,
        barParams,
    }: {
        fooParams: T extends StateNameWithFooParams ? StateParams[T]['fooParams'] : undefined,
        barParams: T extends StateNameWithBarParams ? StateParams[T]['barParams'] : undefined,
    } 
) {
    // impl    
}

activateState('started', {
    fooParams: { 
        abc: 'hello'
    },
});
```

I expect not to have to provide `barParams` to `activateState()` function call, since its type resolved to `undefined`.

This is the error given:

```
Argument of type '{ fooParams: { abc: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ fooParams: { abc: string; }; barParams: undefined; }'.
  Property 'barParams' is missing in type '{ fooParams: { abc: string; }; }' but required in type '{ fooParams: { abc: string; }; barParams: undefined; }'.
```

Comment: You'd need to work around it like this: https://tsplay.dev/mxyPBW